# juju bootstrap issue public key

Tags: juju

I set up one node and install juju on it.
The OS is a Ubuntu Cloud Image so must login with:

**ubuntu** username and a private key.

but when I run juju bootstrap : I have this error:

```
ERROR initializing ubuntu user: subprocess encountered error code 255 (Permission denied (publickey).)
```

my environments.yaml file :

```
default: manual
environments:
  manual:
     type: manual
     bootstrap-host: deploy.example.com
     bootstrap-user: training
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Can you ssh into the other machine as ubuntu?

```
ssh deploy.example.com -l ubuntu
```

If that doesn't work, the problem is in your security setup.

From my environments.yaml:

```
manual:
    type: manual
    # bootstrap-host holds the host name of the machine where the
    # bootstrap machine agent will be started.
    bootstrap-host: somehost.example.com

    # bootstrap-user specifies the user to authenticate as when
    # connecting to the bootstrap machine. It defaults to
    # the current user.
    # bootstrap-user: joebloggs
```

That says to me that the bootstrap-user is who you use login.  In your case, you need to login as 'training', not 'ubuntu'.  So try

```
ssh deploy.example.com -l training
```

Or, more to the point, try changing your environments.yaml to

```
bootstrap-user: ubuntu
```